# Tab key cursor movement between textbox

Tags: c#

I have multiple `textbox` when I press the tab key the cursor move to next `textbox`, but the my problem is that movement is not sequential or in other owrd is random movement lets say `textbox1` `textbox2` `textbox3` `textbox4` the movement is `2,3,1,4` so look how to get the movement back to its correct order

since The control move over to the other on entering TAB according to sequence in which they are drag drooped(or created).

I tried to organize the code in designer but that's does not effect the movement

then how to order the cursor movement ?

is theira code in somewhere to modify according to the order i want ?

Comment: The control move over to the other on entering **TAB** according to sequence in which they are drag drooped(or created).

Comment: @ Jamil Exactly, I have noticed that so I am looking for away to re-order that movement by re-order something in somewhere ? I think you know what exactly I want to do ... but where is that code I need to order ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a good step-by-step tutorial on MSDN:

[How to: Set the Tab Order on Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: for sure I search on the net before posting here but not that's what I want... i need to something like @ Jamil said above

Comment: @samer This answer is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: It's also possible to set the `TabIndex` programmatically, but this is the quickest method to reorder the tab order.

Comment: Thanks you both was right... one last question is their away to skip one textbpox from movement ? like the read only textbox

Comment: You can set the `TabStop` property to false.

Comment: Thanks as its easy as it important and annoying :)

Comment: Thanks as its easy as it important and annoying :)